# Отображение сайта на iPad

Tags: ipad, css, javascript

Добрый день!

Проблема в следующем:

[Заходим на сайт](http://krepezhstroy.ru/voltmobi/volt-one-page-4.html) с iPad'a, страница загружается корректно при любой ориентации экрана, затем, при смене ориентации на альбомную, ширина страницы увеличивается и выходит за пределы зоны видимости. Для того, чтобы данную страницу привести к нормальному состоянию, необходимо уменьшить зум, после этого страница отображается корректно.

С портретной ориентацией таких проблем не возникает. В чем может быть причина данного поведения страницы при альбомной ориентации и как это исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: У меня этот сайт нормально отображается после поворота в альбомную ориентацию. Может, от версии Safari зависит? У меня стоит iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: @Anastasia, возможно сейчас нормально отображается (сам еще не смотрел, iPad не с собой), так как обновил meta согласно ответа @Cypher. Спасибо за заботу:))

Comment: Кроме того, прочитал на Хабре, что при использовании данного мета-тега, зум страницы невозможен. Гляньте пожалуйста если будет время и отпишитесь. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, не зумится))

Comment: А как обойти данную проблему? Не сталкивались?

Comment: Нет, не сталкивалась.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что при повороте устройства как раз и происходит зум. Хотел бы я сам знать за каким чертом :). Не хорошо это, конечно, запиливать такие функции. Но у вас адаптивный сайт. Подразумевается, что пользователям и не понадобится зум.

Comment: Ну взять к примеру amason.com, там тоже адаптивная и зуммируется и не глючит при смене ориентации ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```